How acquiring digital badges, certificates,, and degrees affect core learning and retention
Is it true that acquiring a degree, certificate, or badge boost confidence and even have a placebo effect. Suppose I learned a topic thoroughly through a book decades back. Since I had acquired no relevant academic credential tagged to that learning, I myself might me under the impression that I am a novice for that topic or subject today. By logic, there should be no effect to my core learning retention irrespective of acquired academic credentials or not.
Today it has become somewhat of a norm when you do even self learning, you acquire free certificates or badges. Not only they boost your resume, but who knows this might have a kind of a placebo effect boosting confidence that I know that subject. Without a certificate, it is easy to forget that I even spent hours decades back learning a topic!
So seeking opinion of experts what is their thought regarding this culture of tagging learning with badges. Are they illusionary in the sense I may start assuming myself an expert in AI after passing quizzes and assignments?
